# 'Snippit' based django semi-CMS

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I remember reading somewhere on the internets about a half-assed tiny django CMS app, which was basically built on 'snippets' of text.

The idea was, that in the admin, you make a snippet (say a description of a product), give it a name (such as 'google_desc') and call it in a template with something like {% snippet google_desc %} and bam!

I *think* it was [this](http://www.b-list.org) guy that made it, but im not quite sure.

Would anyone know where i could find this piece of awesomeness?

**Edit:** I was after an app or something to plug into my project. Not, an existing website/service.

**Edit 2:** insin got it. I was after [django-chunks](http://code.google.com/p/django-chunks/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [django-chunks](https://github.com/clintecker/django-chunks) to me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [Django Simplepages](http://www.punteney.com/writes/django-simplepages-basic-page-cms-system/)?  Official site [here](http://code.google.com/p/django-simplepages/).

Another project that sounds similar to what you're after is [django-page-cms](http://code.google.com/p/django-page-cms/).

Comment: And quite awesomely, just 2 hours after the question was asked, searching Google for "django snippet sms" (no quotes) gives this question as the second result.

I remember seeing somewhere what you're looking for, but can't recall exactly what it was either.

Answer (score 1):

If you need some more features just checkout django-blocks (http://code.google.com/p/django-blocks/). Has multi-language Menu, Flatpages and even has a simple Shopping Cart!!